# SQL Server : Freetext search with And Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, contains, freetext

Project table `Name` columns contains this data:

1. USA Russia England Canada
2. Canada

Query:

```
SELECT name 
FROM project 
WHERE FREETEXT(name, '"USA Canada"')
```

Result: the query returns both rows.

Expectation: the query should only return 1 row containing USA and Canada

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @hsn A tag for sql-server did exists.